# Using a Pipe with undefined startup values

Tags: javascript, rest, api, angular, pipe

In my pipe file i have this code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(service: any, term: any): any {
    if (term=== undefined) return service.filter(function(service){
      return  service.product_name.toLowerCase().includes("rustic".toLowerCase());
    })

    return  service.filter(function(service){
      return  service.product_name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
  }
}
```

i call above pipe in this template :

```
<div class="searchresult" *ngFor="let service of services |search:term ">
                <div [routerLink]="['/searchresult',service.product_name]" class="searchitem">ID : {{ service.product_name }}</div><br>
            </div>
```

how to know that `service` not ready yet. Because in my application i want to search data from remote rest API (in my VPS hosting). currently i need to wait about 30 seconds before type the keyword to be passed to Pipe. if i type it before 30 seconds, mostly search will failed with return `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. This is because rest API not be loaded yet to service. how to know that my service not already loaded so i can hold the search input to be disable until service ready to used...

every help will be really respected....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your variable `services` is `undefined` at startup?
Maybe set it to an empty array `[]` on application start..

However, change your Pipe like this to make it more robust against failures!

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(services: any[], term: any): any {
    if (!services || !services.length) return []; // check inputs first!
    if (term === undefined) term = "rustic".toLowerCase();

    return service.filter(srvc => srvc.product_name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()))
  }
}
```